# Orchard CMS Lists - how to replicate using Taxonomies

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm new to Orchard but from various blog posts and SO answers it seems that Lists would help me achieve what I want. Unfortunately it seems that Lists have now been deprecated.

The documentation at http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists suggests using Taxonomies instead. Is it possible to achieve the functionality of a List using Taxonomies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use taxonomies to produce a list of content items. Create your taxonomy, add some items to it, attach the taxonomy field to your content type, and select the taxonomy you want to be displayed in the content type settings. Create a content item with a taxonomy selected then go to the url:

> /*taxonomy-name*/*selected-taxonomy-item*

and it should display a list of all items with that taxonomy selected.

However, lists were deprecated and replaced by Projections, I would recommend using these. They are part of core and can be enabled from the backend. You can then create a query with your projection uses. This query determines what items you want displaying. It is pretty nice and simple, just need to play around with it. Let me know if you need more details about it, or probably just googling Orchard Projections will produce some useful links if you need to do some more complex things with it

Comment: Thanks Hazza, I managed to solve it using projections as you suggested.